# Not able to get image file extension

Tags: php, file-extension, getimagesize

I'm using Uploadify to upload an image to the server.
The image is uploaded, and placed in the temp folder of the web server.

Now I need to work with the file beore moving it to it's real location, and I have the following code:

```
// Get the filepath and filename from server temp dir
$sourceFile   = $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'tmp_name' ]; // e.g. c:\server\path\tmp\php159.tmp

// Solution 1 for getting file extension
$fileExt1     = pathinfo($sourceFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // <-- This only returns .tmp

// Solution 2 with getimagesize
list(,,$extension) = getimagesize($sourceFile);
$fileExt2     = $extension; // this only returns the number 2.

// Solution 3 with getimagesize
$img = getimagesize($sourceFile);
$fileExt3 = $img[2]; // this only returns the number 2.
```

I'm not using regex to read filename, because a user may name the file anything, so I have to read file data.

Any sugegstions anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off $sourceFile should be `$_FILES['Filedata']['name']` instead of `$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']` but **only for your first solution**.

Now regarding your solutions/problems:

1. `pathinfo($sourceFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` // should work now
2. `getimagesize()` returns a constant indicating the image type in the second index
3. same as point 2

Keep in mind that `exif_imagetype()` returns exactly the same information as the second index of `getimagesize()`, if you have access to this function it should perform way better.

Now for the image constants, the most common three are:

- IMAGETYPE_GIF = 1
- IMAGETYPE_JPEG = 2
- IMAGETYPE_PNG = 3

Checking is as simple as doing something like this:

```
switch (exif_imagetype($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']))
{
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        echo 'is a GIF';
    break;

    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        echo 'is a JPEG';
    break;

    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        echo 'is a PNG';
    break;

    case default:
        echo 'is something else;
    break;
}
```

**One more thing, it's better to use `getimagesize()` / `exif_imagetype()` than to rely on the file extension, since the extension can be easily changed.**

Comment: Ah, so THAT's what the 2 means :) Thanks.

Comment: I can't use exif_imagetype, at least not on my own computer. It hasn't been compiled with my PHP (I'm using v5.x). I only get `Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()`. (see links in my comment below)

Comment: If you are in windows then enable the dll in the following order                           extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll and make sure we are editing the correct php.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

Your solutions #2 and #3 both work already. From [the getimagesize() manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

> Returns an array with 7 elements.
>   ...
>   Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of the image.

So for a .gif then this should be the integer 2. To get the file extension use `image_type_to_extension()` since you already are using the gd library. eg.

```
$img = getimagesize($sourceFile);
$fileExt = image_type_to_extension($img[2])
```

Comment: +1 for the image_type_to_extension(), however IMAGETYPE_GIF = 1, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

[exif_imagetype()](http://de3.php.net/exif_imagetype) can determine a number of graphics formats, is fast and doesn't even use GD.

> Edit: I see you are already using getimagesize() and have trouble translating the constants. The exif_imagetype() page linked above has a translation of all returned image types that should be valid for getimagesize() as well.

Comment: I only get `Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()`. Others have similar problems: http://www.ivorde.ro/PHP_Error_Call_to_undefined_function_exif_imagetype__on_FreeBSD-35.html and http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,34044

Comment: thanx for the information.... this is really good. it determines the image type using image header (MIME type), so even if a GIF file has some other extension it will detect that image as GIF image type

Comment: @Steven what version of PHP are you using. This function is for PHP 4.3.0 and above.

Comment: @Sureka: exif has to be compiled with PHP, and that is not always the case.